# New immigrant in Germany, SCHUFA score is 328. Why so low?

Tags: germany

For my apartment search I need a [SCHUFA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schufa) query (Auskunft), and I also need a good one.

However, I was pretty surprised as it says my score is 328 out of 600, which is pretty low and a "high risk of bills not being paid".

Is that normal for new inmigrant, and if not, should I contact them and try to rectify it?

Answer (score 3):

The base score (scorewert) that should be used is in procent.

The [Schufa](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schufa) results are based on **known** facts about a person.

- Accounts, Employment, Contracts

  - the amount of each and how they are used/fulfilled

The exact method used is a **business secret** (Geschäftsgeheimnis), as determined by court rulings.

So an *entrant* (Berufsanfänger), will be less known than someone working for 5-10 years.

A new Immigrant, who is also unknown, falls into the same category.

With time a reputation is built, when know facts have been collected.

---

In the past, for an *entrant*, it has always been difficult.

In the present day of computer automation it has become worse, since the aspect that the queried persion is an *entrant* is often not taken into consideration

- the computer (**hallowed be it's name**) says no

  - they (**who do not think**) accept that result

There are of course exceptions ...

- **real estate** (Immobilien) is **not** one of them

---

[Schufa Score - Alle wichtigen Infos im Ratgeber](https://www.maxda.de/schufa/schufa-score/?gclid=CjwKCAiAwZTuBRAYEiwAcr67ObhZ7c-j9icNpI1T34yXg4AMJ9NGPte-7VpkHfHve9GG3H5azBcSKBoCEIcQAvD_BwE)

> **Scorewert**      **Ausfallwahrscheinlichkeit**

```
 >97,5%     Sehr geringes Ausfallrisiko
 95-97,5%   Geringes bis überschaubares Risiko
 90-95%     Zufriedenstellendes bis erhöhtes Risiko
 80-90%     Deutlich erhöhtes bis hohes Risiko
 50-80%     Sehr hohes Risiko
 <50%       Kritisches Risiko
```

Answer (score 0):

There are different types of Schufa certificates. As far as I remember, the one for renting an apartment never had a score written on it (see [image](https://bonitaetscheck.immobilienscout24.de/assets/img/new_solvency-doc-preview-3.png) on, for example, [Immobilienscout24](https://www.immobilienscout24.de/ratgeber/lp/schufa-bonitaetscheck.html?seaid=g_dm&gclid=CjwKCAjw_sn8BRBrEiwAnUGJDoq9f-Fs4DG1Cp0c6FaXsREfwhrJserlq11740G5t4DDsEzMmeZIbRoC_4YQAvD_BwE)).

So first option would be to get a different type of Scufa certificate, without a score (if it is still possible, please double-check it), and see what is written there.

If it will be negative, but one does not have any real negative background (like not paying a rent or credit), one can make a [free GDPR-based Schufa-query](https://www.meineschufa.de/index.php?site=11_3). It will contain a lot of detailed personal information (bank accounts, credits, etc.). If you decide to show it to the landlord, it may help to convince them that your low Schufa score is caused by the fact that you recently immigrated into Germany, and not by negative history. One may also consider to strikethrough some really private personal information from there, so that only relevant information is shown to the landlord.

In general, it might be harder to convince landlord to rent you a flat when you just arrived. Please see [my tips from another answer](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/a/13852/13223) for more details, as well as other related questions and answers:

- [Is it possible to find an apartment for rent in Germany before coming there and looking for a job/contract?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/327/is-it-possible-to-find-an-apartment-for-rent-in-germany-before-coming-there-and)
- [Strategies to find an house/apartment in Germany for expats](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/6574/strategies-to-find-an-house-apartment-in-germany-for-expats)